# Linking Coded Domain to Featureclass Field in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: esri-geodatabase, domains, enterprise-architect

Im using *Sparx Enterprise Architect* (Ver. 13) to create an ArcGIS Geodatabase.

I have defined a *Coded Value Domain* but how do I link this Domain to a field within my Featureclass?

I watched the intro video, searched the docs.

Comment: Enterprise Architect is a little complex. For modeling geodatabases, ArcGIS diagrammer software is the best solution.

Comment: I don't think ArcGIS Diagrammer works with ArcGIS 10.3 or later!? (https://community.esri.com/thread/118432)

Answer (score 0):

To assign a domain to an attribute in a Featureclass open the attributes table in Enterprise Architect, open the selection box for the row *Type* and scroll down to *Select Type...*

[image: View of features in Enterprise Architect]

Now you can choose the domain you need in the browser.

[image: Selecting the domain]